# Crystal report error - No Area with specified name was found

Tags: java, crystal-reports

I am getting below error when retriving report via crystal report. But this issue occuring time to time. I get below error on first trial, but it succeeds on second trial.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No Area with specified name was found
    at com.inet.report.Engine.getArea(Unknown Source)
    at aero.champ.reporting.utils.ImageDimensionUtil.setImageDim(ImageDimensionUtil.java:23)
    at aero.champ.reporting.utils.ImageDimensionUti
```